# Let's get critical: May 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Politics Stack Exchange](http://politics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What was the reasoning behind putting the right to keep and bear arms in the US Constitution?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/what-was-the-reasoning-behind-putting-the-right-to-keep-and-bear-arms-in-the-us)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What governmental power does the Monarch hold in Great Britain?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1237/what-governmental-power-does-the-monarch-hold-in-great-britain)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Why is denying global warming associated with conservatives?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/why-is-denying-global-warming-associated-with-conservatives)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [What are the reasons for not letting protection against the criminals be left to trained professionals?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1244/what-are-the-reasons-for-not-letting-protection-against-the-criminals-be-left-to)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Is the "War on Terror" successful? How can success be determined?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/is-the-war-on-terror-successful-how-can-success-be-determined)

  **Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 4)
- [Illegal vs Unconstitutional](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1202/illegal-vs-unconstitutional)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Would the expanded background checks have prevented past shooting incidents?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1260/would-the-expanded-background-checks-have-prevented-past-shooting-incidents)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Why do labor laws exempt certain job roles from overtime?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1267/why-do-labor-laws-exempt-certain-job-roles-from-overtime)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Is there any evidence that legalizing prostitution decreases violence against women?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1257/is-there-any-evidence-that-legalizing-prostitution-decreases-violence-against-wo)

  **Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 4)
- [Why are there so many unscheduled/premature elections in Israel?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1180/why-are-there-so-many-unscheduled-premature-elections-in-israel)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

Comment: The fact that my answer to #4 - which has more references than you can shake a stick at but goes against liberal dogma - got a "needs improvement:3" tells me all I need to know about whether people even remotely bother evaluating posts for quality and not political agreement. The only 2 other equally hated posts both had answers with opinions not backed up by references (one of which was to a very poor-answerability question).

Comment: Also, I wonder how 3 people decided that my answer for the last one - which took several painstaking hours to compile from disparate sources - is "OK but can be found elsewhere on Internet" - which is what my understanding of "Satisfactory" means...).

Comment: @DVK Why are you assuming the scores are based on _your_ answers, and your answers alone? The question and couple of the other answers in #4 have issues, your answer does not. Also, "satisfactory" doesn't necessarily mean "can be found elsewhere on Internet", it could also mean "ok, but... boring".

Comment: @YannisRizos - To me I judge based on is it an expert quality answer.  I may not like the answer but if it is well written and expert quality I Still give it credit. Having references helps but does not automatically make it well written

Comment: @YannisRizos - unless I'm gravely mistaken, the official grounds for site evaluation was very explicitly "**whether information contained in the answers is better or worse than one contained on the Internet**", not "is the question perfect" or "is one of the answers worse than others". IOW, **a question with one excellent and one crappy answer should be judged by the former only**. If I'm wrong, I would appreciate a link explaining the evaluation process in clearer way, thx.

Comment: @YannisRizos - BTW, I also don't see any issues with that question, you're welcome to comment on it if you see some and I can try to edit it into shape if I buy into your arguments, as it's an interesting question :)

Comment: @DVK ["Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net."](http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/q/1339/101)

Comment: @YannisRizos - if that quote was a SE question, I'd VTC it as "not constructive". It doesn't explain how to judge "stacking up" at all. I'm going by details I vaguely remember from podcasts in the last couple of months that mentioned evaluations, which is why i'm not fully certain I got the intended rules correctly.

Comment: There's nothing to explain @DVK, each one of us is free to evaluate the questions and answers based on their own criteria. You may only care for the top voted answer, I tend to read every upvoted answer. And I consider a thread that has upvoted opinion heavy and unreferenced answers as in need of improvement.

Comment: @YannisRizos - http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1347/site-self-evaluations-are-there-any-official-rules-guidelines-on-how-to-assess

Comment: @YannisRizos - "upvoted opinion heavy and unreferenced answers as in need of improvement" - fair enough, I agree with that one. I actually included that caveat in my meta question, in a more precise format.

Comment: I'll ask someone from SE to chime in, but I highly suspect the answer will be along the lines of "use your judgement". If you think about it, if they had concrete guidelines, they'd put them in self eval Meta question, wouldn't they?

Comment: @DVK I went back and read question #4, and although your post would be a very good answer to an `Are Police legally required to protect us` question It does a poor job of tying the knot on the `Why don't we leave depend on a  police force to protect us.`

Comment: @SamIam - the answer to "why" is a simple "because police are NOT there with the purpose of protecting us". The rest of the answer is a referenced proof of that statement.

Comment: @DVK you come at a lot of answers with a rather obvious political dogma, so I think it's to be expected that some will disagree with the particular decisions as to which sources to cite based on their own political dogma. 'tis the nature of the beast, it seems, with a site dedicated to politics.

Comment: As it stands now, I think the challenge with this site is that there just aren't enough contributors. When there's only a dozen or so regular contributors, that's going to magnify any particular bias much more than if there were 120 contributors. Evaluating questions is important I think but really isn't the issue at the moment. It's eyeballs. The site needs a whole lot more of them.

Comment: @DA. - if you bother reading my comment, I was referring to tons of cites **from law cases** vs. no cites. What does that have to do with political dogma?

Comment: @dvk citations in and of themselves don't make for bias, but the selection of and analysis of can certainly be influenced by particular dogma. That's not necessarily good or bad, but is likely to be expected to some extent.

Comment: Also, am I reading the results correctly? Was there only a total of 5 evaluators? If so, does this really mean anything? (other than we need a lot more eyeballs?)

Comment: @DA. - it could be a limit of 5 evaluators per question, but you are probably correct.